# Modify IO layers used by backticks

Tags: perl

i.e. being able to do

```
$result = `my command`;
```

using `:raw`, `:utf8`, etc.

Any special variables I don't know about, alternative methods or modules that can be used?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well I don't know if there are any special variables, but why not use open() for that task? You can specify the encoding on pipes like you would on files:

```perl
open(my $cmdin, "-|:raw", "your command");
my $result = join('', <$cmdin>);
close($cmdin);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use popen:

```
open (my $fd, "-|", $prog, @args) 
    or die "Couldn't start $prog: $!";
do_whatever($fd);
while (<$fd>) { ... };
```

Or if that's not enough you should look at [IPC::Open2](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.14.1/ext/IPC-Open2/lib/IPC/Open2.pm) and its cousin Open3.